# .htaccess rule gives 500 error for php file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I saw another stackoverflow answer to come up with this current setup.
I want requests to http://myserver.com/book/1234 to actually show the content from php file http://myserver.com/book.php?id=1234

So my .htaccess looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^book/(.*)$ /book.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Notice the bottom two lines allow me to use url's like http://myserver.php/login to actually pull up http://myserver.php/login.php   This is working correctly.
But I get a 500 Error when I try calling http://myserver.com/book/1234  What is wrong?

Comment: You don't need the `QUERY_STRING` there. That means you'd need to enter `book/1234?id=1234` for it to work.

Comment: Hmmm.  I changed the line to look like this: RewriteCond % ^id=([0-9]*)$    but I still get the 500 error.

Comment: No, remove the entire line - sorry, that was implied.

Comment: Please check your error log for more info about the 500 ISE.

Comment: Thanks Mike Rockett.  Taking out the entire QUERY_STRING line did the trick!

Comment: I have posted the solution as an answer - please accept it in case others catch the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is instructing the server to only do the rewrite if the query string is present. As a result, the rule would only work if you requested `/book/1234?id=1234`.

Removing the line below will allow your rewrite to work.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
```

Comment: does it work with `/book/1234?id=1234&utm_source=adwords`, doesn't look like `^....$`

Comment: `RewriteRule ^book/(.*)$ /book.php?id=$1 [L]` is intended to rewrite `book/1234` to `book.php?id=1234`. If you want to have other query parameters appended, then you will need to add the `QSA` flag at the end so it becomes `[QSA,L]`. Then, if you request `book/1234?utm_source=adwords`, it will be rewritten to `book.php?id=1234&utm_source=adwords`.